# Worker pools and multi-tenant queues with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, worker

I work on a web application that is a multi-tenant cloud based application (lots of clients, each with their own separate "environment", but all on shared sets of hardware) and we're introducing the ability for a user to batch up work for later processing.  The types of batched work really isn't important, it's just of sufficient quantity that doing it without a work queue isn't really practical.  We've selected RabbitMQ as our underlying queue framework.

Because we're a multi-tenant app, we don't necessarily want clients to be able to cause lengthy queue process times for another client, so one idea that we've floated up is creating a queue on a per client basis and having a shared worker pool pointed across ALL our client queues.  The problem is that, to the best that I can figure, workers are directly bound to a specific queue, not an exchange.  In our ideal world, our client queues will still be processed, without one client blocking another, from a shared worker pool that we can grow or shrink as necessary by launching more workers or closing down idle ones.  Having workers tied to a specific queue prevents us from this in a practical sense, as we'd frequently have lots of workers just idling on a queue with no activity.

Is there a relatively straight forward to accomplish this?  I'm fairly new to RabbitMQ and haven't really been able to accomplish what we're after.  We also don't want to have to write a very complex multithreaded consumer application either, that's a time sink in dev and test time that we likely can't afford.  Our stack is Windows/.Net/C# based if that's germaine, but I don't think that should have a major bearing in the question at hand.

Answer (score 6):

You could look at the priority queue implementation (which wasn't implemented when this question was originally asked): https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html

If that doesn't work for you, you could try some other hacks to achieve what you want (which should work with older versions of RabbitMQ):

You could have 100 queues bound to a topic exchange and set the routing key to a hash of the user ID % 100, i.e. each task will have a key between 1 and 100 and tasks for the same user will have the same key. Each queue is bound with a unique pattern between 1 and 100. Now you have a fleet of workers which start with a random queue number and then increment that queue number after each job, again % 100 to cycle back to queue 1 after queue 100.

Now your worker fleet can process up to 100 unique users in parallel, or all the workers can focus on a single user if there is no other work to do. If the workers need to cycle through all 100 queues between each job, in the scenario that only a single user has lot of jobs on a single queue, you're naturally going to have some overhead between each job. A smaller number of queues is one way to deal with this. You could also have each worker hold a connection to each of the queues and consume up to one un-acknowledged message from each. The worker can then cycle through the pending messages in memory much faster, provided the un-acknowledged message timeout is set sufficiently high.

Alternatively you could create two exchanges, each with a bound queue. All work goes to the first exchange and queue, which a pool of workers consume. If a unit of work takes too long the worker can cancel it and push it to the second queue. Workers only process the second queue when there's nothing on the first queue. You might also want a couple of workers with the opposite queue prioritization to make sure long running tasks are still processed when there's a never ending stream of short tasks arriving, so that a users batch will always be processed eventually. This won't truly distribute your worker fleet across all tasks, but it will stop long running tasks from one user holding up your workers from executing short running tasks for that same user or another. It also assumes you can cancel a job and re-run it later without any problems. It also means there will be wasted resources from tasks that timeout and need to be re-run as low priority. Unless you can identify fast and slow tasks in advance

The first suggestion with the 100 queues could also have a problem if there are 100 slow tasks for a single user, then another user posts a batch of tasks. Those tasks won't get looked at until one of the slow tasks is finished. If this turns out to be a legitimate problem you could potentially combine the two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can just have your pool of workers all consume the same unique queue. Work will then be distributed across them and you'll be able to grow/shrink your pool in order to increase/decrease your work processing capacity.

Comment: I'm not asking about assigning multiple workers to the same queue, I'm sort of asking about the reverse.  I want a finite pool of workers to consume from a large (let's call it ~500) number of queues.

Comment: I have experimented first-hand with this kind of approach and it's not pretty: it's hard to find a suitable heuristic to process all these queues. Do you process first the fullest queues? Or the ones with the older messages? In both case, you're out of the AMQP protocol and have to start dealing with the Rabbit management API. Then you think: let's have the same number of queues than workers and you add some consistent-hash mapping between 500 Qs and the worker queues. Then you realize that a single queue and n workers competing on it is all you need.

Comment: I've a similar requirement, however I want to ensure the messages from a particular customer are processed sequentially. A contact isn't deleted before it was created etc. Is there some configuration or setup of RabbitMQ that can do this yet share the queue between workers? (Is this a new Q...?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you don't use RabbitMQ's vhosts and have your app login to RabbitMQ and authenticate on a separate connection for each user.

This doesn't mean that you can't have a worker supervisor that assigns workers to one user or another. But it does mean that all messages for each user are processed by entirely separate exchanges and queues.

Answer (score 0):

Workers are assigned 0+ queues, not exchanges.

The logic for which tasks will be taken from which queues for each worker is implemented in the class indicated via `CELERYD_CONSUMER`, which is by default `celery.worker.consumer.Consumer`.

You can create a custom consumer class ro implements whatever logic you like.  The hard part will be deciding the details ofthe "fairness" algorithm you want to use; but once you've decided that, you can implement it be creating a custom consumer class and assigning that to appropriate workers.